Sampling from a Superexponential Population in Polynomial Time
I'd like to sample from a well-defined population of super-exponential size with uniform probability among the population. For example, say the population is the set of unique permutations of combinations without replacement of the integers {0, 1, ..., n-1}, where the sequence length is AT MOST n.
Valid members for n=5:
(0,1,2,3)
(0,1,2,4,3)
(1,)
()

Invalid members for n=5:
(1,3,3) # No repeated elements
(0,1,2,3,4,5)  # Only in the range [0,4]

How would you write a function sample_bounded_permutations(n) to return a random permutation in polynomial time where each valid member is equally-likely to be selected? The brute force approach of computing all population members and sampling from the list is, of course, at least factorial time.

I didn't know how general a method you wanted. But, "I can write a dynamic programming algorithm to count them" seemed pretty general to me...

Here is a method for converting from something you can count with dynamic programming to a random sampling algorithm. It is something that I invented for myself, and I've yet to encounter a dynamic programming problem that this didn't let me solve.
First write out the simplest and most straightforward dynamic programming solution that you can.
def count_bounded_permutations (n):
    count = 0
    current = 1
    i = n
    while 0 <= i:
        count += current
        current *= i
        i -= 1
    return count

Feel free to test this, it works.
Now we'll want to do the same dynamic programming, except create an analysis of the structure. I'll introduce a class for clarity.
class SolutionStructure:

    # This node gives a set of solutions, and a link to previous ones.
    # The parameters are passed in decreasing likelihood of need.
    # The assignments are in how to think about this.    
    def __init__ (self, prev=None, prev_solutions=None, choice=None, multiplicity=1):
        # By which overall choice did we get here? Might not be recorded.
        self.choice = choice
        # How many ways can we get from prev to here? Default 1.
        # When decoded we'll get a number in range(mutiplicity),
        # which is to say 0, 1, ..., multiplicity-1.
        self.multiplicity = multiplicity
        # What came before this decision in these solutions?
        self.prev = prev
        # The promised link to previous solutions.
        self.prev_solutions = prev_solutions

        # Now let's figure out the counts.
        #   this_count: The count of this set of solutions.
        #   total_count: The count of all, including prev_solutions.
        if prev is None:
            # None represents an empty set, has count 1.
            self.this_count = multiplicity
        else:
            self.this_count = multiplicity * prev.total_count

        if prev_solutions is None:
            # No prev_solutions means no solutions.
            self.total_count = self.this_count
        else:
            self.total_count = self.this_count + prev_solutions.total_count

Now with this class, let's rewrite our previous dynamic programming solution to record the structure. It is a fairly straightforward mechanical translation.
def analyze_bounded_permutations (n):
    answer = None
    current = SolutionStructure()
    i = n
    while 0 <= i:
        # 'e' for end
        answer = SolutionStructure(current, answer, 'e')
        # 'a' for add to the permutation
        current = SolutionStructure(current, None, 'a', i)
        i -= 1
    return answer

And to verify that total_count is right, let's rewrite our first function to use analyze_bounded_permutations.
def count_bounded_permutations2 (n):
    return analyze_bounded_permutations(n).total_count

OK, so now we have a data structure with all of the solutions. Let's go back to our class and add a decisions method that will let us get back the decisions that lead to any given solution. Here is the class with our new method.
class SolutionStructure:

    # This node gives a set of solutions, and a link to previous ones.
    # The parameters are passed in decreasing likelihood of need.
    # The assignments are in how to think about this.
    def __init__ (self, prev=None, prev_solutions=None, choice=None, multiplicity=1):
        # By which overall choice did we get here? Might not be recorded.
        self.choice = choice
        # How many ways can we get from prev to here? Default 1.
        # When decoded we'll get a number in range(mutiplicity),
        # which is to say 0, 1, ..., multiplicity-1.
        self.multiplicity = multiplicity
        # What came before this decision in these solutions?
        self.prev = prev
        # The promised link to previous solutions.
        self.prev_solutions = prev_solutions

        # Now let's figure out the counts.
        #   this_count: The count of this set of solutions.
        #   total_count: The count of all, including prev_solutions.
        if prev is None:
            # None represents an empty set, has count 1.
            self.this_count = multiplicity
        else:
            self.this_count = multiplicity * prev.total_count

        if prev_solutions is None:
            # No prev_solutions means no solutions.
            self.total_count = self.this_count
        else:
            self.total_count = self.this_count + prev_solutions.total_count

    # What set of decisions lead to the solution n? (Counting from 0.)
    def decisions(self, n):
        if self.total_count <= n:
            # No answer possible. Maybe throw an exception?
            return None

        # We will produce the answer as a linked list of decisions.
        # From last to first.
        start = []
        tail = start
        current = self
        while current is not None:
            if n < current.total_count - current.this_count:
                # Give prev_solutions.
                current = current.prev_solutions
            else:
                n -= current.total_count - current.this_count
                # Made this decision.
                # A decision looks like (choice, number).
                decision = (current.choice, n % current.multiplicity)
                tail.append([decision])
                tail = tail[-1]
                # Now we have to find which solution out of prev to use.
                n = n // current.multiplicity
                current = current.prev

        # Now decode the linked list into a list.
        reversed_decisions = []
        if 0 < len(start):
            # We have decisions.
            node = start[0]
            while 1 < len(node):
                reversed_decisions.append(node[0])
                node = node[1]
            reversed_decisions.append(node[0])
        return list(reversed(reversed_decisions))

You can test this method.
# Prints [(None, 0), ('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('e', 0)]
print(analyze_bounded_permutations(3).decisions(5)

And now we need to turn this set of decisions into a bounded permutation.
def find_bounded_permutation (n, i, structure=None):
    if structure is None:
        structure = analyze_bounded_permutations(n)

    available = list(range(n))
    answer = []
    for decision in structure.decisions(i):
        choice, j = decision
        # Ignore choice None and 'e'
        if choice and choice == 'a':
            if j < len(available) - 1:
                # Swap.
                available[j], available[-1] = available[-1], available[j]
            answer.append(available.pop())
    return answer

You can spot check it to verify that the output makes sense. (The order is probably not what you naively expect.)
for i in range(count_bounded_permutations(3)):
    print(i, find_bounded_permutation(3, i))

And, finally, let's randomize it.
import random
def sample_bounded_permutations (n, structure=None):
    if structure is None:
        structure = analyze_bounded_permutations(n)
    i = random.randrange(structure.total_count)
    return find_bounded_permutation(n, i, structure)

This solves your problem in a way that can be applied to the solutions of a wide range of other dynamic programming problems.

Steps that I would take to do this:

I would choose the list length randomly
I would create the permutation with that length

Here is my first try:
def sample_bounded_permutations(n):
    def generate_sequence(available, length):
        if length == 0 or len(available) == 0:
            return list()
        length -= 1
        chosen = random.sample(available, 1)
        next_available = [x for x in available if x not in chosen]
        return list(chosen) + generate_sequence(next_available, length)

    max_length = random.randint(0, n)
    return generate_sequence(list(range(n)), max_length)


print(sample_bounded_permutations(5))

Unfortunately, it is not as random as I would like. This is because if the list length is, for example, 1, we have only five permutations of that length. The probability of the list length being 1 is equal to the probability of the list length being 5, where we have (5!) permutations. As a result, we are more likely to see outcomes such as (1) and (2) far more frequently than outcomes like (1,0,2,4,3).
You could test it with this code :
results = [tuple(sample_bounded_permutations(5)) for _ in range(325)]

frequency_count = Counter(results)

for result, frequency in frequency_count.items():
    print(f"Result: {result}, Frequency: {frequency}")

Now, to introduce an additional layer of randomness, I will select a number between 0 and n based on the number of possible permutations of that length.
Here it is :
def weighted_random_selection(n):
    weights = [math.factorial(n) / math.factorial(n - m) for m in range(n + 1)]
    total_weight = sum(weights)
    normalized_weights = [weight / total_weight for weight in weights]
    return random.choices(range(n + 1), weights=normalized_weights, k=1)[0]


def sample_bounded_permutations(n):
    def generate_sequence(available, length):
        if length == 0 or len(available) == 0:
            return list()
        length -= 1
        chosen = random.sample(available, 1)
        next_available = [x for x in available if x not in chosen]
        return list(chosen) + generate_sequence(next_available, length)

    max_length = weighted_random_selection(n)
    return generate_sequence(list(range(n)), max_length)


print(sample_bounded_permutations(5))

I wanted to select a number between 0 and n, where the probability of choosing a specific number m is n!/(n-m)!. This is because there are n!/(n-m)! different permutations of length m using the numbers from 0 to n-1.

This is attempting to back its way into a solution of just the one problem, rather than trying to come up with some sort of general method.

@btilly how come? It will generate a random permutation of a objects that OP wants.
