What is the time complexity of the following algorithm and is there any optimization I can do?
Problem: Given an array that sums to 0, find the maximum number of partitions of it such that all of them sum up to 0 individually.
Example:

input: [-2, 4, -3, 5, -4]
output: 2 (which are [[5, -2, -3], [-4, 4]]. These are not necessarily needed as the output of the algorithm)

My solution:
I find any subset from the initial list that sums up to 0 and is a proper subset (function f in the code below finds that any subset). Its disjoint is also an answer. Then I run the same algorithm on what I found.
def return_n_subsets(balances):
    balances.sort()
    
    n = len(balances)
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    @cache
    def f(sp, cur_sum):
        if sp == len(balances):
            return None
        if balances[sp] == -cur_sum:
            return [balances[sp]]
        
        if cur_sum > 0: #early stop since there would be only positive numbers from here on
            return None
        #include sp
        out1 = f(sp+1, cur_sum + balances[sp])
        if out1 is not None:
            out1 = out1[:] #############################
            out1.append(balances[sp])
            if len(out1) != len(balances): #condition to not return the input itself
                return out1
        #dont include sp
        out2 = f(sp+1, cur_sum)
        if out2 is not None:
            out2 = out2[:] ##############################
            return out2
        return None

    sub1 = f(0,0)
    if sub1 is None:
        return 1
    [balances.remove(i) for i in sub1]
    subsets = [sub1, balances]
    out = 0
    while True:
        new_subsets = []
        for balances in subsets:
            balances.sort()
            f.cache_clear()
            sub1 = f(0, 0)
            if sub1 is not None:
                [balances.remove(i) for i in sub1]
                new_subsets.append(balances)
                new_subsets.append(sub1)
            else:
                out += 1
        if len(new_subsets) == 0:
            break
        subsets = new_subsets
    return out

My computation of the time complexity:
I am going through every subset of the original list and at each iteration im also creating a copy of the output list (lines in code with lots of hashes after them). This is Nx2^N. Then I get 2 subsets of size N/2 each and I run 2xN/2x2^(N/2). Then I run 4xN/4x2^(N/4) and so on and so forth.
Overall time complexity: O(Nx2^N + Nx2^(N/2) + Nx2^(N/4) ...) = O(Nx(2^N + 2^(N/2) + 2^(N/4) ...)) = O(Nx2^N)

Is my computation of the time complexity accurate?  I am confused since I am using memoization it would appear that I am actually solving only N*S problems where S is the possible sums which would range from the sum of all the negative numbers to the sum of all the positive numbers. A bit confused as to which is accurate.
Are there improvements I can make to my algorithm?


I suspect the optimum solution involves sorting the input array and then working outwards away from zero using heuristics to shortcut and refute lines which cannot possibly contain a valid answer. I'd hope for something around O(N^2) or at worst O(N^3). There might perhaps be a bitwise representation that is even faster.

Putting aside the complexity analysis, your code just doesn't work. I ran it on [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3] and got 5.

I also tried running it on your example input, and got 4 instead of 2.

Ohh.. my pasted code has out initialised with a value 2. It would overestimate everything by 2. I pasted a part of a much bigger code and forgot to make this change. The code is wrong even after that. It passed all the test cases on leetcode and also beat 100% of other solutions and hence I assumed it is right. Thank you for your example. The code is wrong because "I cannot find any 0-sum subset and try to break it further till I can and say that is the solution."

Your problem contains the 3-Partition Problem as almost a special case. Namely, can we partition a set into sets of 3 that each have the same sum. That is strongly NP-complete. Meaning that not only is it NP-complete, but there is no pseudo-polynomial approximation. So you should not expect better than an exponential worst case.
I did not walk through your complexity analysis, but the end result sounds reasonable.
Now can we be faster? In worst cases? No. In practice? Let's pull out my old cheat sheet.

A* Search
Subset sum pseudo-polynomial approximation.
My personal "turn dynamic programming into explicit solutions" trick. Only personal because nobody seems interested in learning how to do it for themselves.

So here's an outline of how I would do it.

Sort the elements in decreasing absolute value, then increasing value.
Separate the 0s out.
Turn that into tuples (abs(element), count_negatives, count_positives).
Create a naive upper bound for A* search. (Based on pair negs with pos, hope that all else turns into as many groups of 3 as possible.)
Do an A* search for the best division.

So for your example there are no 0s. After sorting we get [5, -4, 4, -3, -2]. The naive lower bound will be 2 (we can pair -4, 4, and divide the remaining 3). The A* search will immediately verify that this works.
Unfortunately there are two problems:

That A* search really needs persistent data structures to code efficiently, and nobody has a good Python library for that. Why does it need that? It's because it allows you to very cheaply say, "Take this element here, and that element there out of this long list" without having to use a lot of memory on the modified copy of the array.
I've done too many by hand "dynamic programming to explicit solutions" and want to write a library for it next. That lets us take a first element and find all of its solutions of lengths 2, 3, 4, etc. And then try those solutions in lexicographic order. Which, oh geez, we repeat to try to find a good solution for the next one. And so on.

I'm in the process of writing both libraries, but they are medium large projects, so no promise on when they will be done.
But that should give an idea of how much this could be optimized.

What distinguishes regular DP from 'DP to explicit solutions'?

I'm intrigued by the two problems + libraries you mention. If you are open to discussion / collaboration, please feel free to invite me to a stackexchange chatroom to chat.

Are you sure that pseudo-polynomial solution is not possible? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#:~:text=.-,Pseudo%2Dpolynomial%20time%20dynamic%20programming%20solutions,-%5Bedit%5D
I do not know much about complexity theory but it would seem that I had come up with the same algorithm that they have mentioned here and it is pseudo polynomial

@Dave I made a stab at a general solution for DP to explicit solutions a while ago at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78498209/sampling-from-a-superexponential-population-in-polynomial-time/78582332#78582332 but it wasn't very good. Still it gives a flavor.

@DillonDavis Sorry, but my ideas are not really at a point where I am in a position to collaborate, and my life is dominated by real life. Still you can look at the thing I pointed Dave at, then thing, "How do we handle multiplication?" If you can handle Catalan numbers, you're about where I am conceptually. As for the other, there is a literature on persistent. If anyone does it before me, I'll happily concede defeat.

@figs_and_nuts Did you notice your estimated 2^n factor? That's not pseudo-polynomial. That said, I don't have a proof, but I'm quite sure that it is impossible.

[Not important but] Your justification behind A* search "really needing persistent data structures to code efficiently" seems quite suspect. I have never read any piece of literature discussing A* search, remotely or adjacently allude to such an idea. Even if you do utilize one, the discrepancies in contrast  to a traditional implementation would be negligible.

@figs_and_nuts Yes, no pseudo-polynomial solution is known. Find one and you overturn the whole world of computer science.

@M.A. Believe or disbelieve as you want. But we're searching through different modifications of an array of size O(n). Your choice is between doing O(n) work to make copy without persistent data structures, or O(log(n)) work to make a modified copy with persistent data structures. That's a pretty big efficiency difference.

The code I have given is pseudo-polynomial time only but it is the wrong algorithm. Surprisingly it passed all the tests on leetcode and beat 100% so i didnt look for logical bugs in it. I am assuming that "I can find any 0-sum subset from the array and then take its disjoint to find another 0-sum array. Now I can apply the same thing on these arrays I have found and keep going till I reach arrays that cannot be partitioned and this way I get all the 0-sum arrays (and max number at that too)". This is wrong. Example in the next comment

Example Input: [-17, -9, -9, -3, -2, -1, 11, 12, 18]
Output that my algorithm can land upon: [[17, 3, 2, 1, -11, -12], [-18, 9, 9]] and now these cannot be broken further
But, first partitions --> [[12, 11, -2, -3, -9, -9], [-17, -1, 18]]. Then [12, 11, -2, -3, -9, -9] can partitioned further into [[11,-2,-9],[12,-3,-9]]

Shouldn't we always remove pairs of negative and positive numbers summing to zero after step 3 (even if A* will likely not be much impacted) ? Even if there exists partitions there they are combined in other ways, I don't see that those partitions can add anything, if we have [a, x1..xn], [-a, y1..ym] then [a,-a], [x1..xn, y1..ym] must be part of a partition with the same number of partitions.

@HansOlsson yes. I just had missed that angle at first.

Below is a memoized recursion-based solution. It is still exponential time, and its runtime scales with the values in the array, but I figure it can provide a known-good baseline for other solutions.
from math import comb, factorial
from collections import Counter

def find_max_partitions(arr):
    counter = Counter(arr)
    
    num_zeros = counter[0]
    counter[0] = 0

    num_signed_pairs = 0
    for x in list(counter):
        count = min(counter[x], counter[-x])
        counter[ x] -= count
        counter[-x] -= count
        num_signed_pairs += count

    arr = [x for x, c in counter.items() for _ in range(c)]
    
    k = 1
    while (count := count_valid_partitions(arr, k)) > 0:
        k += 1
    return k - 1 + num_zeros + num_signed_pairs

def count_valid_partitions(arr, k):
    if k == 1:
        return 1 if arr and sum(arr) == 0 else 0
        
    arr = list(arr)
    sums = [0] * k
    
    count = _count_valid_partitions(arr, k, sums, {})
    
    count -= sum(count_valid_partitions(arr, i) * comb(k, i) * factorial(i) for i in range(1, k))
    count //= factorial(k)
    return count
        
def _count_valid_partitions(arr, k, sums, memo):
    if not arr:
        return 1 if not any(sums) else 0
        
    elem = arr.pop()

    count = 0
    for idx in range(k):
        sums[idx] += elem
        
        key = tuple(sorted(sums)), len(arr)
        val = memo.get(key)
        if val is None:
            val = memo[key] = _count_valid_partitions(arr, k, sums, memo)
        count += val
        
        sums[idx] -= elem
    
    arr.append(elem)
    return count

Let N be the size of your input array, A be the sum of the negative values, B be the sum of the positive values, and P be the maximum number of partitions (our output), the time complexity will be O(N*(B-A)^(P+1)).
I've already implemented a few optimizations like stripping off zeros and signed pairs, making these into partitions of their own, and sorting the intermediate sums to avoid a P! duplication of effort. There are still a number of optimizations that could be made, but most of them will have little to no effect on performance. We could cache the result of smaller k-value calls to count_valid_partitions (negligible overall), early-exit the count once its known to exceed some required threshold (also negligible savings), or stuff like avoiding creating new N-tuples at every step. Overall, these won't change the time complexity.
There is one more major optimization that could be made to this approach however. Take the remaining items, work out the 3SUM solutions, and take the largest set of independent 3-tuples from those. There exists a maximal partitioning where all of these independent 3-tuples are either (a) each their own standalone partition or (b) are scattered into distinct partitions (no two elements of the same tuple being assigned to the same partition). This can significantly reduce the search space, leading to large performance gains (still the same time complexity however). Even for the case of just one tuple, the search space is cut in third.
There is still potential to do better though. Offhand, I have an idea for a potential O(N*(B-A)^(P/2)) solution, however its drastically more complex, has larger overhead / hidden constants, and probably won't be feasible. Additionally, you could go for a O(P^(N/2)) time meet-in-the-middle solution. The naive implementation would have an equal space complexity O(P^(N/2)), but there are efficient time-memory tradeoffs you can make to lower the space complexity by more than you increase the time complexity by (such as decreasing memory by a factor of M and increasing time by sqrt(M)).

Even a greedy 3-tuple collection could make that optimization very interesting!
